# How i can fetch what is typed between 2 UITextViews on iphone?

Tags: iphone, compare, uitextview, fetch

i have two UITextView items, how can i fetch what is written using a button on iphone?

Imagine something like a translate app, the user enters a word in UITextView 1 and by pressing the button the UITextView 2 is getting filled with data.

Answer (score 1):

`UITextView` has a property `text`. Simply use this.

Set up `IBOutlet`s for `textView1` and `textView2`. Then have the button do something along these lines:

```
-(IBAction)moveTextOver:(id)sender {
    [textView2 setText:textView1.text];
}
```

To get fancier, you can have a method `-(NSString *)transformText:(NSString *)text` that translates or does whatever you like. Then use

```
-(IBAction)moveTextOver:(id)sender {
    [textView2 setText:[self transformText:textView1.text]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an IBAction method that is linked to a button and in that method read the "text" property of the textView or textField, do your calculations on it and assign the results to the text property of thee second field.